# Generate a random number of enemies to appear on screen

Tags: c#, xna, random

I am currently trying to create 2d shmups. I am trying to:

- Generate a random number of enemies to appear on screen
- Whatever number is generated will then be added to my List (the list is used to keep track of enemies). to load that number of textures.
- I would also like to keep a collection of Vectors to determine the positions the enemies will spawn randomly.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 List <Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int numberOfEnemies = rnd.Next(1,5); // I would like to generate between 1 and 5.
 if (enemies.count < numberOfEnemies){
     enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("alienship");// one of the vectors from the collection of vectors will go here
 }
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're having, then?

Comment: Looks like you just need to change `if` to `while`. If you need help with basic looping constructs like this, an introductory programming tutorial or StackOverflow may be more appropriate.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to go about adding a random number of "enemies" to my List.

Comment: Google "C# for loop".

Comment: It seems your asking how to use *loops* and *Random*. While you intend to use these in a game, these are *not* game development specific aspects of programming. As mentioned, previously, you should ask about using these things on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A few changes to your code are needed to achieve your objectives:

First, a caveat; most of what you are looking to do can be done using basic coding principles. If you're struggling to put this together, I'd recommend you look through the C# Programming Guide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx). There's absolutely nothing wrong with attempting to learn the language, but making the jump straight into game development can be tricky.

Now then, the first thing you want to do is change your **if** clause to a **for** or **while** loop.

**While** loop:

```
List <Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();
Random rnd = new Random();
int numberOfEnemies = rnd.Next(1,5) // I would like to generate between 1 and 5.
while (enemies.count < numberOfEnemies){
   enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("alienship"),// one of the vectors from the collection of vectors will go here;
}
```

**For** loop:

```
List <Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();
Random rnd = new Random();
int numberOfEnemies = rnd.Next(1,5) // I would like to generate between 1 and 5.
for(; enemies.count < numberOfEnemies; ){
   enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("alienship"),// one of the vectors from the collection of vectors will go here;
}
```

Note that there are multiple ways to accomplish this, and while both are syntactically correct, the **while** loop is much cleaner in this case. In C#, and indeed most languages, changing your **if** clause to a loop (**for**,**while**) causes the code to repeatedly execute everything within the clause while a condition is met.

With this change made, you now have multiple enemies being created, however, none of them have a position initialized yet. To do this, we will extend the existing code.

```
List <Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();
Random rnd = new Random();
int maxSpawnX = 800;
int maxSpawnY = 600;

int numberOfEnemies = rnd.Next(1,5);
while (enemies.count < numberOfEnemies){
   int x = rnd.Next(0, maxSpawnX);
   int y = rnd.Next(0, maxSpawnY);
   enemies.Add(new Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("alienship"), new Vector2((float)x, (float)y)));
}
```

First, note that this assumes the constructor for your Enemy class looks something like

```
public Enemy(Texture2D texture, Vector2 location) { ... }
```

We've added two new variables to make life easier (maxSpawnX, maxSpawnY), and inside our loop we've created new *x* and *y* integers which hold the result of our random number operations. We insert those variables into a newly initialized Vector2, casting them to floats as we do so (using (float)).

With this done, the code now works and generates a random number of enemies in random locations. However, there are a few more details that need fixing.

The Random.Next(min,max) method provides a psuedo-random number within min(inclusive) and max(exclusive). That exclusive part is rather important here, as you state you want a random number between 1 and 5. However, as written in the code (rnd.Next(1,5)), you're actually generating a number between 1 and 4. To fix this, we need to increment that number by 1. We also have the same issue in our x and y variables, so those need fixed as well. (This code is not displayed as an exercise for the question-asker)

The only other issue I have with the code as it is now is your use of Content.Load for each enemy created. If each enemy in the loop were using a different texture, this could be an acceptable way to do this, and even as it is now, it works. However, it's likely not the most efficient way to do this as you're calling unneeded logic every time you create an enemy. A better way to do this is to move the Texture2D load outside of the scope of that loop, so the texture load is only called once.

```
List <Enemies> enemies = new List<Enemies>();
Random rnd = new Random();
int maxSpawnX = 800;
int maxSpawnY = 600;
Texture2D enemyTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("alienship");
int numberOfEnemies = rnd.Next(1,5);
while (enemies.count < numberOfEnemies){
   int x = rnd.Next(0, maxSpawnX);
   int y = rnd.Next(0, maxSpawnY);
   enemies.Add(new Enemy(enemyTexture, new Vector2((float)x, (float)y)));
}
```

With this done, you don't waste computing time looking up and possibly loading duplicate textures. (granted, I believe XNA is smart enough to recognize that this texture has already been loaded and just passes a reference to the existing object)